# Rounding integers

Tags: python, list

I have *15* numbers,

```
[1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100, 150, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]
```

I have people entering the quantity and what I want is it to round to the lowest number. hence if someone enters `36` it will round to `30`.

Comment: Welcome to to the Stackoverflow community. In order to participate, it's best to include code of what you have tried rather than asking for a solution. Plenty of people will help you with your questions but it's bad practice to ask someone to come up with the solution for you.

Comment: Sorry Chris, thanks for the tip, will do in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution. It should be O(log n); it relies on the fact that the list is sorted.

```
L = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100, 150, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]

def roundit(x,n):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]
    elif x[len(x)/2] > n:
        return roundit(x[0:len(x)/2],n)
    else:
        return roundit(x[len(x)/2 :],n)
```

Result:

```
>>> roundit(L,36)
30
>>> roundit(L,77)
70
>>> roundit(L,150)
150
```

Comment: Is it O(ln(n)) ? getting half of the tab with x[0:len(x)/2] takes log(n), no ?

Comment: @MatthieuW, `O(ln(n))` = `O(log(n))`, I just called it a natural log.

Comment: @MatthieuW, OK, I google around and it seems that "my notation" is not used; hence, I changed to what is standard. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: My remark was more about time took by copying part of the list. If you take this time into account you are O(n)

Answer (score 7):

`bisect` will do it in O(log N):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> L = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100, 150, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]
>>> L[bisect.bisect(L, 36) - 1]
30
```

or with pure python and O(N):

```
>>> L = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100, 150, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]
>>> next(elem for elem in reversed(L) if elem <= 36)
30
```

assumed the `L` list is sorted. Otherwise `L.sort()` it before.

Comment: +1, but you should not call the variable `l`. (violates pep8)

Comment: It's important to note that bisect assumes that the list is sorted, and won't work properly with a list that is not.

Comment: If you're using iterators, why not `reversed`?

Comment: `L` renamed, sorted list assumed, iterator reversed, thanks to all comments.

Comment: Thanks all this site is amazing!

Comment: `L` is a bad variable name, too... go for lowercase for normal variables.

Answer (score 7):

With pure python:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100, 150, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]
>>> x = 36
>>> max(n for n in numbers if n <= x)
30
```

*note:* Does not rely on numbers list being sorted.